# correct canvas height and width not being passed to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

Canvas element not being passed with correct height and width to a function, for now I fixed the problem by again assigning the height and width of the canvas after it has been passed to the accepting function. As I am new to this so I want to know if this is a problem with canvas or not?.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    calling_function = function(eventObj){
       //some code
        ajaxOptsFtn =  {
                    url: '/xyz_data/',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: form_vals,
                    success: function(resp){
                        //initialisation for function.
                        if(resp.var_ready === true){
                        //dynamically adding canvas element.
                        var canvas_obj = $('<canvas/>').css({width:160, height:240});
                        $(clicked_element).children('canvas').remove();
                        $(clicked_element).append(canvas_obj);   
                        //intilise other arguments with some values
                        var x = 30;
                        var y= http://abcs.com/dds.jpg;
                        var z = resp.apparel_img_url;
                        var nl = gamma_value;
                        var wD = 23;
                        var wU = 26;

                        acceptingFunction(canvas_obj[0],y,z,x,n,wU,wD);
                     } 
                     else{
                         console.log('some other message');
                     }
                 },
        };
        if (data.var_ready) {
            $.ajax(ajaxOptsFtn);
        }
        else{
            console.log('some message'); 
        };
    };

    acceptingFunction = function(canvas_obj,y,z,x,n,wU,wD){

        canvas = canvas_obj;
        console.log("canvas passed height and width:"+ canvas.height +","+canvas.width);
        console.log("re assigning expected values");
        canvas.width = 160;
        canvas.height = 240;
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        //some code
        AimageObj.onload = function () {
            //some code
        };

        BimageObj.onload = function () {
        //some code 
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You must set the size of the canvas using its *attributes*, not CSS - for example:

```
var canvas_obj = $('<canvas/>').attr({'width': 160, 'height': 240});
```

If you don't do this the canvas element will default to size 300 x 150 pixels which is only stretched by CSS (like an image).

And likewise you also read the same attributes/properties when you want to get the canvas' size.

I have [written a blog post that explains this in details](http://abdiassoftware.com/blog/2013/11/how-to-properly-set-size-of-the-canvas-element/) - it's too long for SO but here is the essential part:

> If we don’t set any actual size for the canvas’ source bitmap it will
>   default to 300 x 150 pixels as per [specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element). If you now set the
>   CSS size of the element to lets say 900 x 450 pixels what happens is
>   that those 300 x 150 pixels are simply scaled to the new size as the
>   CSS applies to the element while the default 300 x 150 applies to the
>   source bitmap (ie. the image). The applied CSS rule doesn’t do
>   anything with the actual bitmap size.
>
> It would be exactly the same if the canvas was an image, which works
>   in a similar fashion: it has the image element and then the source
>   bitmap – the image itself. If you choose to use a different size for
>   the element than what the image is, the image is simply stretched but
>   its original data stays the same. There are no more or less pixels in
>   the original image.

Comment: As my question was for understanding the problem.So, @Ken Fyrstenberg, could you please explain why does the canvas element default the size to 300 x 150 if we we set the size of canvas by css. I mean Why can't we  change the css? that is the crux of my question.

Comment: @Aameer I have written a more in-depth blog post about this [here](http://abdiassoftware.com/blog/2013/11/how-to-properly-set-size-of-the-canvas-element/) which can perhaps fill in the details. I will leave some excerpts from it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's also very easy to do it from an HTML5 standpoint. As Simple as:

```
<canvas id="canvasName" width="160" height="240">
    <p>Sorry, The Canvas element is not supported in this browser :(</p> 
</canvas>
```

Adding the paragraph makes it so that a browser that doesn't support the Canvas (IE6 for example) makes this line pop up instead of the Canvas. But putting this into the HTML5 file makes it simple for drawing the Canvas which can be worked with with Javascript. Just make sure you load the Canvas before you load the Javascript, otherwise it will crash

You would then have to declare it in Javascript with

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

And you can Console.log it to make sure it is connected properly

Comment: @ TheChosenCodeNewb what your good self has mentioned is a way to avoid this problem, but purpose of my question was to understand the cause of the problem.